# XM Cloud - "Unable to connect to the remote server" when viewing a page in Experience Editor

Tags: jss, xm-cloud

When viewing a Site's page in the Experience Editor, the Editor does not load and the following error message is displayed;

`Unable to connect to the remote server`

The CM server logs displays the following entry

```
ERROR [JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `http://localhost:5000`
ERROR Unable to connect to the remote server
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: System
at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5000
Source: System
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

However the page loads correctly when browsing the page directly on the Next app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in my case was due to the field `Predefined application rendering host` on the Site's `Site Grouping` was empty.

Navigate to your Site Grouping - `/sitecore/content/<Headless tenant name>/<site name>/Settings/Site Grouping/<site name>`

In the `Predefined application rendering host` select your `Rendering Host` drop the DropLink.

It's also worth confirming the following fields on the Items listed;

- `/sitecore/content/<Headless tenant name>/<site name>/Settings/Site Grouping/<site name>`

  - `Site name`
  - `Target hostname`
  - `Hostname`
  - `Start Item`
  - `Predefined application rendering host`
- The item referenced by the `Predefined application rendering host` field

  - `Server side rendering engine endpoint URL` - this should be the url and port your `Next` app runs on suffixed by `/api/editing/render`
  - `Server side rendering engine application URL` - this should be the url and port your `Next` app runs on
  - `Application name` - this should match the `Name` and `AppName` in the `package.json` of your next app